# Using a Stopwatch based Func as loop control variable

Tags: c#, while-loop, func, stopwatch

Trying to use a `Func<bool>` as a loop control variable as follows seems to upset Resharper. Given the following Stopwatch:

```
var executionTimeStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
executionTimeStopwatch.Start();
```

This raises a "*Loop control variable is never updated inside loop*" warning:

```
Func<bool> mustStop = () => executionTimeStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS;
while (!mustStop()) // -> function call
{
    // ...
}
```

However, this doesn't:

```
Func<bool> mustStop = () => executionTimeStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS;
var k = false;      // -> declaration
while (!k)          // -> used for loop control
{
    k = mustStop(); // -> explicit update
    // ...
}
```

I don't understand how the result of the execution of these codes could be different; as `mustStop()` depends on the Stopwatch it should evaluate differently each time it is called.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Its just a warning! I think `Resharper` is unaware of whether your condition is a variable or a function. It is just seeing that the variable is not changing inside the loop, so there is a possibility of infinite loop. Also in your case `k` is updated within the loop.

Comment: I agree! Code validations tools aren't all-knowing after all. ;)

Comment: Frankly it is not uncommon to get a false alert from Resharper anyway. Luckily Resharper supports disabling special warnings on such occasions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

No, Both code blocks are not different. In fact compiler will optimize the second block to remove the variable `k` in most cases when compiled with release mode.

Resharper could not prove that loop variable is changed inside the loop since it happens in another method. Simply resharper isn't clever enough to find whether the `mustStop` delegate may return a different value when called multiple times.

You could just ignore the warning or suppress it in this case.

Comment: Thanks! To all, check also answer below (AakashM's): http://stackoverflow.com/a/34658500/2983568

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue within ReSharper, [RSRP 451141](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-451141).

> RSRP-451141 Incorrect Loop control variable is never changed inside
>   loop
>
> The following code will generate an incorrect "Loop control variable
>   is never changed inside loop":
>
> ```
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Function will be evaluated on the same thread as the calling thread
>     /// </summary>
>     /// <param name="function"></param>
>     /// <param name="msInterval">Time to wait between each check of function, in ms</param>
>     /// <param name="msTimeout"></param>
>     /// <param name="timeoutAction"></param>
>     /// <returns>true if function eventually returned true, false otherwise</returns>
>     public static bool WaitForTrueOnSameThread(Func<bool> function, int msInterval, int msTimeout, Action timeoutAction = null)
>     {
>         var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
>         while (!function()) {
>             if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > msTimeout) {
>                 timeoutAction?.Invoke();
>                 return false;
>             }
>             Wait(msInterval);
>         }
>         return true;
>     }
> ```

At present there is no indicated fix timescale.

[RSRP 429291](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-429291) looks pretty similar, too.